# How To Find A Formula For g(x,y,z) when given the plane parallel to it?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

z=8x+5y-2.

I moved everything to one side and the constant to the right to get:

8x+5y-z=2.

The definition is that every point is equal to whatever c is (in this case, 2) so I equaled everything to 2.

8x=2

$$x=\frac{1}{4}$$

5y=2

$$y=\frac{2}{5}$$

-z=2

z=2

Then I made g(x,y,z)=$$\frac{1}{4}x+\frac{2}{5}y+z=2$$

Comment: What does $g$ stand for?

Comment: It's just the funciton... Like f(x,y,z).

Comment: But _what_ function? All you’ve given in your question is the equation of a plane and then you perform some mysterious calculations based on it. You haven’t really stated exactly what it is that you’re trying to accomplish. It seems that you’re trying to find a plane parallel to the given one, but you’re last equation is certainly not that.

Comment: z=8x+5y-2 is the given function.